# Save document directories data in Mac

Tags: ipad, icloud, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an application where lots of data get saved in Document Directory of application for later sending to a webservice. This saving in documents was done for offline access of the application as the data will not be sent to webservice at that time. My client has created hundreds of items in offline mode and now he is unable to sync them. We are not able to find the issue of not getting it synced. But the main task is to save that data from getting lost. If he deletes the application. That data will be lost.

Is there any possible way through which I can sync his app document data with iCloud or iTunes app sync. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mac or iPad? Your subject contradicts your tags.

Comment: mine is iPad. What is contradicting here?

Comment: "...in Mac" in your question, that's what.

Comment: i want to transfer/save what is in my app's document directory to my Mac